# Models for first logic sentences

Tags: first-order-logic

As homework i have to solve same exercise about first order logic, i did that but i am not so sure that it's correct and if i understood good during the lecture, i ask if there is somebody who can help me please.

i have to find at least a model for the following sentences :

1.∃x.[A(x) ∧ ∀y.R(x, y)]

Domain:{1,2}

I[A]={1}

I[R]={(1,2),(1,1)}

2.∀x.¬∀y.[R(x, y) → R(x, x)]

Domain:{1,2}

I[R]={(1,2);(2,1)}

3.∃x∃y.R(x, y) ∧ ∀x∀y.(R(x, y) → ∃z[R(x, z) ∧ R(y, z)]) ∧ ¬∃x.R(x, x)

Domain:{1,2}

I[R]={(1,1}

For the last one i have a doubt, my question is if it had to be necessary to rename the variable considering that x,y have different quantifiers and they doesn't connect between each other

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct.

Comment: For 3, you have $¬∃x.R(x, x)$ and thus $(1,1) \in I[R]$ wil not do.

Comment: For the last one i cannot find any model, except I[R]= empty set . Is it correct?